# How to get Document Name in office JS

Tags: office-js

How can I get the document name in Office JS? I have tried to get that from `Office.context.document` but there is not any value for the document name.

The document URL has the document name `Office.context.document.url` Is there any other way to get the document name directly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there is no other way. But it's an interesting idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Noted. Thank you Rick,